# Value distribution based on ranking

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to solve following problem. I have amount in `D2` amount to distribute in `C2` is the min amount in `E2` is calculated to how many client the `E2` could be distributed.
I would like to do de distribution based on the ranking until the amount in `D2` is used up.
Outcome should be 200 to the clients ranked 1, 2, and 3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Need more clarification what you actually want. Have a try on below formula-

```
=IF(COUNTA($B$3:B3)>$E$2,"",$D$2/$E$2)
```

[image]